# Calling javascript function on form submit (with jquery form validation)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form set up with the jQuery Validation plugin.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9q865xof/

And I have this (non-jquery) javascript function from how my form was validated before adding the plugin.

```
function busregform(form, password) {

// new input for hashed password
var p = document.createElement("input");

// create element
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

// clear plaintext password 
password.value = "";

// submit the form
form.submit();
return true;

}
```

With the hex_sha512() function in its own file too.

The idea here is to post the password from the form through busregform() to create a hashed password to then post for my PHP script to process.

I have tried adding this to my validation jquery code:

```
submitHandler: function(){
  var pw = $("#pass").val();
  var form = $("#business-reg-form");
  busregform(form,pw);
}
```

With no luck... Not sure what to do now. I'm thinking I should use ajax?

How can I call busregform() when the plugin-validated form is submitted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `busregform` method is expecting a dom element reference for `form` so you need

```js
$('#business-reg-form').validate({
  rules: {
    address: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6
    },
    email: {
      required: true,
      email: true,
      minlength: 6
    },
    company: {
      required: true
    },
    pass: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6
    },
    confirmpw: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 6,
      equalTo: "#pass"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function() {
    var pw = $("#pass");
    var form = $("#business-reg-form");
    //pass the dom element reference
    busregform(form[0], pw[0]);
    return false;
  }
});

function busregform(form, password) {

  // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
  var p = document.createElement("input");

  // Add the new element to our form. 
  form.appendChild(p);
  p.name = "p";
  p.type = "hidden";
  p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

  // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
  password.value = "";

  // Finally submit the form. 
  form.submit();
  return true;

}

if (!window.hex_sha512) {
  //stub method
  window.hex_sha512 = function(value) {
    return 'hex_sha512-' + value;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form method="post" name="business_regform" id="business-reg-form" action="">
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="company name" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="address" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="password" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" name="confirmpw" id="confirmpw" placeholder="confirm password" required />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" id="business-reg-submit" value="submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ze3b38xf/) - You can inspect the request using the network tab to see the hashed password

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Arun. However when I `echo $_POST['p'];` on the page it posts to, there is no value. Any idea why this may be?

Comment: @beyondit01 were you able to check the request using network tab

Comment: @beyondit01 that means your PHP code itself is not getting executed, isn't it

Comment: Nevermind. I now see that p is posted, but has no value.

Comment: @beyondit01 can you check what is the value returned by `hex_sha512(password.value);`... to to log it using `console.log(hex_sha512(password.value);)`

Comment: @beyondit01 sorry I think it should be `var pw = $("#pass");` then `busregform(form[0], pw[0]);`

Comment: @beyondit01 you will also have to empty the confirm password field

Comment: It's not clearing the values so I don't think they're getting passed into busregform(). But it is creating the p input.

Comment: @beyondit01 sorry... not sure what you meant

Comment: The created "p" shows up in the form data under the network tab, but has no value. Also the password and confirm values don't get cleared by the `busregform` method. I don't think it's getting the values of `form[0]` and `pw[0]`, what do you think? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: At this point without seeing the problem case, there is nothing much that can be done.... if you are familiar with debugging tools... in the `busregform` method log the values of `password` and see what is happening there... if you have a live link where the problem is reproducible, share it

Comment: Wow, it works now... I don't think I even changed anything from last time. Thank you Arun!